# PERL PAR Packer MYSQL libmysql_.dll

Tags: mysql, perl, par, packer

I have perl scripts which do some update/insert in mysql db. I packed the perl script using [`PAR::Packer`](https://metacpan.org/pod/PAR::Packer). I copied it on the other machine(where perl is not installed) and run the PAR package it fails throwing error as the **libmysql_.dll** is missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to include libmysql_.dll as part of your PAR package. Specify the path using -l option as shown.

> > perldoc pp |ack "-l\b"
>
> ```
> -l, --link=*FILE*|*LIBRARY*
>     packed file. Also accepts names under library paths; i.e. "-l
>     ncurses" means the same thing as "-l libncurses.so" or "-l
> ```

Comment: Thanks Ashok for answering this question. really helpfull